# How to fix "Type caught or thrown must be derived from system.exception" error for a wpf project in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, overflow

I'm trying to create a validation strategy for user input. But I keep getting a CS0155 error.

I've tried throwing an exception but it doesn't get rid of the error.

```
    catch (OverflowAction)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    "{0}.Validate: Int32 overflow (\"{1}\").",
                    GetType(), str);

                string errmsg = Properties.Resources.OverflowError;
                return new ValidationResult(false, errmsg);
               //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
```

I expect the validator to catch the exception and return an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that your `OverflowAction` class does not inherit from `Exception` (or derived one).

See [CS0155](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0155) error documentation.

> Only data types that derive from System.Exception can be passed into a catch block.

`OverflowAction` should looke like

```
class OverflowAction : Exception
{
    // ...
}
```

---

You might be confusing `OverflowAction` with [`OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=netframework-4.8) ...

Comment: class EmptyOrInt32Rule : ValidationRule

Comment: as you can see my class is already using ValidationRule. How can I add Exception to this?

Comment: That is not an `Exception` class. Only an `Exception` can be `catch`'ed.

Comment: Yup. Thats it. Dumbest mistake ever. OverflowException it is Thanks